# Is a single installation available for WSO2 IS and WSO2 ESB products?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

1. To reduce the memory footprint we are looking for single installation for WSO2 IS and WSO2 ESB products, such that both WSO2 IS and WSO2 ESB can shares the same application server and resources. Is a single installation available for WSO2 IS and WSO2 ESB products?
2. Also I would like to know, can we customize the WSO2 IS/WSO2 ESB login page? Customization could be changes to the layout, labels, logos.

Answer (score 0):

[WSO2 API Manager](http://wso2.com/api-management/try-it/) is a complete solution for designing and publishing APIs, creating and managing a developer community, and for scalably routing API traffic.

**It leverages proven, production-ready integration, security, and governance components from the WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus, WSO2 Identity Server, and WSO2 Governance Registry.** In addition, it leverages the WSO2 Data Analytics Server for analytics, giving you instant insight into APIs behavior.

Since all WSO2 products are opensource, you can customize for your own purposes. You can find the source code in [Github](http://github.com/wso2/)